# Parsing XML with SAX

Tags: java, xml, sax

I´ve been trying to read a XML file with some tags like this one

```
  <node id="2148488688" lat="38.9029581" lon="-77.0226998" version="1" timestamp="2013-02-10T01:15:22Z" changeset="14974828" uid="67236" user="jfire"/>
```

and I´m getting an Exception in a specific tag value "id" saying this

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2148488688"2938

My code looks like this:

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    temp = ""; 

    if(qName.equals("node")) {
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(attributes.getValue("lat"));
        double longi = Double.parseDouble(attributes.getValue("lon")); 
        int id = Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue("id"));
        interseccion = new Interseccion(Integer.valueOf(id), lat, longi);

    }   
}
```

the Exception is thrown when I parse the "id" value.

I have no idea why this is happening.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Can u try parselong instead of parseInt

Comment: It worked. Thank you

Comment: Great. You are welcome